Packaging pygtk application using pyinstaller or pydeploy
Hello professional developers,
I am a beginner with Python and started using PyGTK to implement a table-style treeview. Since I'm using Windows, I installed and have been working with MSYS64. Here are the details of my environment:

OS: Windows 11
Python Version: Installed version is 3.12 in my PC, and I am using Python 3.11.7 through MSYS64.
Tool: Visual Studio Code

The program works perfectly on its own, and I wanted to distribute it by converting it into an EXE file for others to use. The EXE is created without issues, but when I run it, I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

I've tried adding the path 'C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages' during the PyInstaller process, but I'm still facing import errors after execution. I have searched Google and asked ChatGPT, but due to my limited experience, I haven't resolved this yet. I've also tried with 'pydeploy', but it returns the same error... Could anyone please help me out?
When I tried to run the application, I got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample.py", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
[20084] Failed to execute script 'sample' due to unhandled exception!

Python 3.12 and 3.11.7 are different versions in the sense that a user installs modules to a version (or environment). So unless you have installed modules, it wont be there

it is also helpful creating a requirements.txt file...

finally,  if using python on windows, why not just install the latest version here: https://www.python.org ?
